How is differential notation defined for two functions?
I heard about the differential notation for ODEs before, but have not yet found any rigorous definition. So far I had the impression that it is define for e.g. rewriting the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}(x) = f(x, y(x))$, where $f$ is a function of $x$ as $dy = f(x,y(x))dx$. Now however I found following formula (simplified, see formula 14 in this paper), where we have these $d*$ expressions, but both symbols  $x$ and $\sigma$ are actually functions of $t$, $\epsilon$ is also some function. For simplicity you can assume that they are all functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.
$$dx(t) = \epsilon \big(\frac{x(t)}{\sqrt{(\sigma(t))^2+1}}\big)\, d\sigma(t)$$
Here we obviously cannot apply the same idea as above, which leads me to believe that there must be a completely different definition. So my question is, how exactly can we transform this equation into a more conventional notation for differential equations, and what definitions do we need to make sense of it?

It is exactly the same idea, just with the independent variable $x$ in your concept (which corresponds to $\sigma$ in the second, while $x$ in the second is your $y$) composed with some function of $t$. Differentials at different locations are not the same. The $dx(t)$ notation here is just making that explicit.
